# Reference for HUP as Distinct from its Underlying Cause (i.e. Fourier Transform between Position and Momentum Space)

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, education

I am writing a paper for an applied optics journal and seeking a concise reference to help dispel the following misconception about how the HUP arises in quantum optics.

At one point i cite the fundamental limit to a beam's angular spread (and therefore ability to confine it) and the beam's width, which is of course owing to the Fourier transform relationship between a field's spatial distribution and its distribution of directions (in wavevector space).

I hear constantly from people in my optics field that this is how the HUP manifests itself in light and that this is part of light's quantum nature. I find this constant mistake really irritating, firstly owing to the arrogant authority with which people seem to cite it (but my wrath and other psychological issues are not your problem to solve) but, more importantly, because it is a real hurdle to anyone's understanding if they really want to study quantum optics, where there is no position representation and the CCR shows up between other observables. I'm working with a PhD student in this position, and their thoughts on this are thoroughly confused by the authority of respected people in our department.

So, we all know the story: CCR means, through Stone-Von Neumann, that there is a FT relationship between representations in eigenfunctions of any pair of operators fulfilling the CCR. Then one uses the purely mathematical properties of the FT to derive the Heisenberg inequality and all the rest of it. By mathematical, NOT physical analogy, an exactly analogous inequality holds between a beamwidth and the beam's diverge.

But i would love to find a concise reference that makes the mistake of conflation of the FT's properties and the HUP explicit. One has to gather quite a bundle of material to show this in a clear light. This of course is not the point of my paper, and i would just like to cite something concise. Obviously, real workers in quantum optics do not have this misconception: we're talking about a paper / reference that would be accessible to someone with a general physics background.

I would, in summary, like a concise little reference to add to my following proposed passage in our paper:

*This ultimate limit is the minimum value of the product of the angular spread of a beam and its beamwidth that arise by dint of the Fourier transform relationship between the beam's spatial and angular (wavevector space) distribution, which is mathematically analogous  to, but not the same physics as, the Heisenberg inequality in quantum mechanics, the latter arising from the Fourier transform relationship between position and momentum co-ordinates.*

Comment: Hoping that I do not misunderstand you the Fourier Transform relationship between the aperture field and the radiation pattern is superbly written by  Silver: https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.15390/page/169/mode/2up and the actual "engineering analog" to the HUP is in this classic by Schelkunoff & Friis https://archive.org/details/AntennasTheoryAndPractice1952/page/n195/mode/2up

Comment: I don’t get this: HUP does NOT arise from FT.  There’s a good discussion on the *analogy* between HUP and FT in Crawford’s “Waves” in the Berkeley Physics series.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Which, unless i am mistaken, is precisely what i am saying and i am asking for a concise reference to dispel this believe. But HUP DOES imply that the coordinate transformation betwee respective co-ordinate systems wherein two conjugate (in the sense of fulfilling the CCR) operators is the Fourier transform: this is a not so simple consequence of [Stone-von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–von_Neumann_theorem#Reformulation_via_Fourier_transform)

Comment: SvN for finitely many degrees of freedom is “easy”, but for fields (infinitely many degrees of freedom) it’s not so clear (there are inequivalences), and this would be the case here as you need continuous (and thus infinitely many) frequencies for FT so I’m not sure about approaching this using SvN…